# dir-pagination angularjs in table ng-repeat - while changing page, at first all rows are appearing for a moment

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, pagination

I am a beginner in AngularJS and have applied dirpagination in my tables. Everything works fine except that when I navigate to another page of my table by clicking on the dir-pagination page buttons, at first the table's height increases and all the rows are shown for a second, then the correct range is shown. How can I avoid this behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-hover nbt-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>heading1</th>
      <th>heading2</th>
      <th>heading3</th>
      <th>heading4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table1">
    <tr dir-paginate="value in viralities|itemsPerPage:10" pagination-id="value-paginate">
       <td><span ng-bind="value[2]"></span></td>
       <td><span ng-bind="value[1]"></span></td>
       <td>{{ value [7] | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'}}</td>
       <td>{{ value [8] | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> 
<dir-pagination-controls pagination-id="value-paginate" class="pull-right"
   max-size="10"
   direction-links="true"
   boundary-links="true" >
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

Comment: Share your code here please .

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have added my code. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't find a solution yet. A bit urgent. Can anyone suggest anything? Could this be a css problem of the outer div or the table having/not having a height property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding the following CSS -

```
.table > tbody > tr {
    transition: background 0.0s;
}
```

This stopped the flickering. Hopefully this will help other beginners struggling with such problem. :)